# PHP CLI: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() even with mysql module enabled

Tags: mysql, php, php.ini, php-cli

I try to run a PHP script from the command line, but get the following error:

```
Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

However, the `mysql` module is loaded:

```
root /var/www/scripts # php -m | grep mysql
mysql
mysqli
pdo_mysql
```

I am on a Debian machine, so all modules are being loaded in their own .ini file:

```
root /var/www/scripts # php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-apc.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini
```

So even though the `mysql` module has been loaded, I still get said error when trying to call `mysql_connect()` in the PHP script.

Any ideas?

PS: Running the script via Apache works fine.

Comment: Did you have a look to your php error log file to look for additional information?

Comment: No information in error log, since I run the script from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this problem seems to be both easy and strange (?) alike:

```
php -c /etc/php5/cli/php.ini -nf script.php
```

Why do I have to specify the `php.ini` file on command line again, if the interpreter says it loads that ini file anyway, even when one does not specify it explicitly?

Comment: You probably have two different versions of PHP installed on your system.